# Erro de permissão no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-permission

Estou adicionando uma função no aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo no android studio, que faz ligações direto do app, porem este erro esta pedindo algum tipo de permissão, sendo que já adicionei permissão no meu AndroidManifest. 
[image: erro]

Comment: a forma de conceder permissões foram todas mudadas na versão "M" (23) do android, veja aqui um bom tutorial sobre o assunto:
[Sistema de Permissões em Tempo de Execução, Android M ](http://www.thiengo.com.br/sistema-de-permissoes-em-tempo-de-execucao-android-m)

Comment: ainda to apanhando com essas edições do stackoverflow, ririri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adiciona isso no seu import:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;

String[] perms = {"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,perms,permsRequestCode);
```

e o suficiente.